# How to change INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR when server @Consumes JSON and request is empty

Tags: api, rest, jackson, jax-rs, endpoint

When i make a request to my JAX-RS path with an empty body I am getting error 500 as a response. If I send a body with {} is ok since it interprets that is a JSON.

I would like to be able to return the error code 400 BAD_REQUEST since in my opinion this is a client error.

```
@PUT
@Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/up")
public Response signUp(Credentials credentials) {
```

I am using jersey, and for the JSON mapper this library:

```
 org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:2.22.2'
```

Comment: That seems strange that a library as large as that would behave in such a way. What does the stack trace say is the source of the 500 error?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom provider to deserialise your JSON payload and hook up your logic. I assume you are using JAXB annotation in your classes.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

import javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONJAXBContext;
import com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONUnmarshaller;

@Provider
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class MyJsonReaderProvider<T> implements MessageBodyReader<T> {

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type,
                              Type genericType,
                              Annotation[] annotations,
                              MediaType mediaType) {
        return type.isAnnotationPresent(XmlRootElement.class);
    }

    @Override
    public T readFrom(Class<T> type,
                      Type genericType,
                      Annotation[] annotations,
                      MediaType mediatype,
                      MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers,
                      InputStream inputStream) throws IOException,
            WebApplicationException {
        try {

            JAXBContext jc = JSONJAXBContext.newInstance(type);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();

            JSONUnmarshaller jsonUnmarshaller = JSONJAXBContext.getJSONUnmarshaller(unmarshaller);
            T object = (T) jsonUnmarshaller.unmarshalFromJSON(inputStream, type);
            return object;

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            throw new BadRequestException("Bad Request");
        }
    }
}
```

Register the provider in your javax.ws.rs.core.Application

Comment: While I don't doubt that this will work, it would be a shame if the thread starter had to go to that length.